# Positional parameters in a script read with the source builtin in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I have noticed some weird behavior when sourcing another script within my shell script. The script that I am sourcing to setup the environment in my shell script takes an optional argument, e.g.

```
source setup.sh version1
```

However in my shell script I have also have command line argument variables. For example:

```
./myscript.sh TEST 1
```

Inside `myscript.sh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh
source setup.sh
echo ROOT version setup $ROOT_SYS
...more of the script
```

The problem that I have noticed with my script above is that the `$1` argument (`TEST` in this example) is used in the `source setup.sh` command. This causes the command to become

```
source setup.sh TEST
```

which of course fails as `setup.sh` does not have a version `TEST`.

I solved this problem by editing my script to below.

```
#!/bin/zsh
source setup.sh version1
echo ROOT version setup $ROOT_SYS
...more of the script
```

The `source` command now does not pick up the `$1` argument.

Why/How does the source command pick up the $1 argument when I am running my shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because source executes the code of `setup.sh` as if it was in place, so when `setup.sh` access, say, `$1`, the value it has is that of the first argument of the actual script. If you want to avoid that you could either execute it:

```
setup.sh
```

or, if you need to get back some variables or values from it, change it to return the result in form of an output, something like:

```
ROOT_SYS=`setup.sh`
```

Finally, as you figured out, the `source` keywords also allows providing arguments to the scripts, but it bypasses current arguments if you don't provide any.

Comment: Thanks Diego. So in my script I could just ./setup.sh instead of source setup.sh? the source setup.sh sets up a command in the shell (sets path etc ) which I use in the script will this still be done with ./setup (I can not see why it wouldn't)?

Comment: If your script actually sets variables to be used in the calling script, you have to `source` it, but then, either the read script ignores command-line arguments, or you provide them explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Diego. I have just added the argument to my setup.sh as I need to use source

Answer (score 3):

Historically, unix shells didn't allow any arguments to be passed to scripts called with the `.` built-in (`source` is an alias of `.` available in bash, ksh and zsh). The `.` built-in means “act as if this file was actually included here”.

In bash, ksh and zsh, if you pass extra arguments to the `.` built-in, they become positional parameters (`$1` and so on) in the sourced script. If you pass zero arguments, the positional parameters of the main script remain in effect. In those shells, `.` behaves rather like calling a function, though not perfectly so (in particular, in bash, if you modify the positional parameters inside the sub-script, the modification is seen by the main script).

A simple way of avoiding this kind of difficulty is to only ever define functions (and perhaps variables) in the subscript. Treat it as a code library, such that merely sourcing it has no effect, and then call functions from the sub-script to actually do something.